# How can I fail a maven build if some unit tests are ignored

Tags: maven, jenkins, surefire

I'm trying to find the best way to fail a Maven build if some tests are ignored (usage of `@Ignore` annotation) and don't want to reinvent the wheel. So far I thought about four options :

1. Configure `maven-surefire-plugin` to fail a Maven build if some JUnit unit tests are ignored. The issue is that I checked the plugin's documentation but could not find anything about ignored tests, so is it even possible ?
2. Use any other maven plugin that fails the build if it detects JUnit unit tests using @Ignore without proper comment (using `@Ignore("JIRA ticket ID : simple reason")` is ok, but raw `@Ignore` is not). Does such a plugin exist ?
3. Parse surefire result file in order to detect that JUnit tests have been ignored (IMHO not the cleanest way as this doesn't allow to differentiate `@Ignore` from `@Ignore("JIRA ticket ID...")`)
4. use a Jenkins pre-build step that checks if `find ${project.build.testSourceDirectory} -name "*Test.java" | xargs grep -l '^@Ignore\s*$'` returns any file name, and fails if it is the case (maybe it's the fastest, cleanest way to do it, and it allows us to improve the regexp to ensure that a JIRA ticket is associated to this @Ignore annotation)

What would you do ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to my own question, maybe it can save some time to other people.

I finally decided to write a shell script that scans the `src/test/java` directory (provided trough a `TEST_SOURCES_PATH` environment variable) and prints out errors for every @Ignore annotation missing a valid comment. The script is run as a pre-build step.

**Requirements :**

Detect all java Test files having an @Ignored test with no comment or with a comment not matching a given regular expression. Fail the build if any error is found.

**The script :**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Variables declaration
path=$TEST_SOURCES_PATH
ignoreAnnotationPattern="^\\s*@Ignore"
ignoreCommentDetectionPattern="^\\s*@Ignore\\s*(\\(\"(.*)\"\\))?\\s*$"
validIgnoreCommentPattern="^JIRA\\s[A-Z]*-[1-9][0-9]*\s:\s.*$"
errorsCounter=0
# Change internal field separator to iterate over newlines instead of whitespaces
IFS_backup=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
# Start detection
echo "Detection of malformed @Ignore annotations in test files started..."
# First find all test files containing an ignored test
testFiles=$(find $path -name "*Test.java" | xargs egrep -l $ignoreAnnotationPattern)
if [ ! -z "$testFiles" ]
then
  for testFile in $testFiles
  do
    # Then keep only lines with the @Ignore annotation
    lines=$(egrep $ignoreAnnotationPattern $testFile)
    for line in $lines
    do
      # try to extract the @Ignore comment
      if [[ $line =~ $ignoreCommentDetectionPattern ]]
      then
        # if the comment is not valid then print out a message and increment errors counter
        if [[ ! ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} =~ $validIgnoreCommentPattern ]]
        then
          echo "Test file '"$testFile"' contains a malformed @Ignore annotation: '"$line"'."
          errorsCounter=`expr $errorsCounter + 1`
        fi
      fi
    done
  done
fi
# Restore initial IFS value
IFS=$IFS_backup
# Exit based on detection result
if [ "$errorsCounter" != 0 ]
then
  echo $errorsCounter" errors were found, aborting build !"
  exit 1
else
  echo "No errors were found, resuming build."
fi
```

**Sample output :**

```
Detection of malformed @Ignore annotations in test files started...
Test file 'src/test/java/MySeventhTest.java' contains a malformed @Ignore annotation: '@Ignore("XXX-999")'.
Test file 'src/test/java/MySecondTest.java' contains a malformed @Ignore annotation: '@Ignore'.
Test file 'src/test/java/MySixthTest.java' contains a malformed @Ignore annotation: '@Ignore("See JIRA XXX-99")'.
Test file 'src/test/java/MyFourthTest.java' contains a malformed @Ignore annotation: '@Ignore("See JIRA XXX-999 : smart reason")'.
Test file 'src/test/java/MyTest.java' contains a malformed @Ignore annotation: '@Ignore("")'.
5 errors were found, aborting build !
```

**Advantages :**

- fast detection done before the java build (fast feedback)
- valid ignore comment pattern can be easily modified

**Possible improvements :**

- Provide more details about the error
- Call JIRA web service in order to check that the ticket exists and is not closed

Comment: Sounds like a job for Checkstyle ?